# Connected components of a space are a singletons.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I was doing my homework when this question appeard.

If $X$ is a discrete topological space, then all the connected components of $X$ are singletons.

I've proved that. But the converse of that is true?

> If all connected components of $X$ are singletons then $X$ is discrete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. $\mathbb Q$, the space of rational numbers with usual topology is a totally disconnected space(only singletons are connected), however it is not discrete.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically what Sahiba Arora said: Recall that a set $S$ is discrete in a topological space $X$ if every point $x \in S$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $S \cap U=\{x\}$.

So an answer of "no" to "if all connected components of $X$ are singletons then $X$ is discrete?" could consist in a totally disconnected subset $S \subset X$ *such that $S$ is dense is the larger space.* The counterexample of $\mathbb{Q}$ is arrived at by noticing that a condition like "each $x \in S$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $S \cap U = \{x\}$" is begging to have a dense set used against it!