# $f : \mathbb R → X$ be a continuous function with respect to the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb R$ and the discrete topology on $X$.

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $X$ be an arbitrary set, and let $f : \mathbb R → X$ be a function that is continuous with respect to the
Euclidean topology on $\mathbb R$ and the discrete topology on $X$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

Can you please help me out with this? I just started a course on topology and I don't know how to prove this.
I know that in a discrete topology, $x_1,x_2$,... Converge to $x$ so $x=x_n$ as {$x$} is open.

Comment: Continuous image of a connected set is connected https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573795/proof-of-the-continuous-image-of-a-connected-set-is-connected

Comment: And connected components of discrete topology are singletons https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344396/connected-components-of-a-space-are-a-singletons

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Describe all continuous function from the reals to the discrete metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522653/describe-all-continuous-function-from-the-reals-to-the-discrete-metric-space)

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Show that $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is open and closed for any $x\in X$.

Comment: The function is continuous by hypothesis, after you that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected with its usual topology.

Comment: How to show that $f^−1({x})$ is open and closed for any $x∈X$? and how does this tell me that $f$ is constant?

Comment: You can prove it sequentially. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected we have that if $A$ is open and closed it should be empty or $\mathbb{R}$.